# How can i filter data from array in object react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, dictionary, filter

This is my data:

```json
 {
    "tester": [
        {
            "title": "test1",
            "id": "1",
            "description": "abcdefg",
            "photos": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"],
            "tags": ["Sample", "Help", "OMG", "Assignment", "Bug"]
        },
```

My solution right now but it can not search each letter in the tags array:

```js
    const fliterdata = trips.filter((filter) => {
    if (searchTerm === '') {
        return filter;
    } else {
        return filter.title.toLowerCase() && //search word in title
            filter.description.toLowerCase() && //search word in description
            filter.tags.map((tag, index) => filter.tags[index].toLowerCase()).includes(searchTerm); //search each letter in the tags array
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you paste your data as code instead of an image?

Comment: What specifically "doesn't work" about your code?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to actually compare the strings. You can do it elegantly by combining all values to match into a single array like this:

```js
const searchTermLowercased = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
const filterdata = searchTerm === '' ? trips : trips.filter(
    ({ title, description, tags }) => [title, description, ...tags].some(
        value => value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTermLowercased)
    )
);
```

Comment: sorry for my poor English, I cannot explain the problem well. and because of the solution you provide, It runs what I want to thank you so so much;-;